# How to create a gzipped tar file without using a lot of RAM?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a gzipped tar file without it taking up a lot of RAM. The Bash equivalent of what I want to do is:

```
tar -cf - -C $INPUT . | gzip -cv - > $OUTPUT
```

I'm using the [tar](https://docs.rs/tar/0.4.13/tar/index.html) and [flate2](https://docs.rs/flate2/0.2.20/flate2/index.html) libraries, which both say they support streaming. I cannot figure out how to stream one into the other. I have tried looking at the `Write` implementors, but do not see a type of stream that fits my needs.

My current implementation has the desired output (namely a .tar.gz file), but it uses up a lot of RAM, especially when the file size is large. The created file also gives "tar: Unexpected EOF in archive" when the input size is large, but is fine with small inputs. This indicates to me that it is not piping the streams as Bash would.

```
use flate2::write::GzEncoder;
use flate2::Compression;
use std::fs::File;
use tar::Builder;

// Create tar archive
let mut archive = Builder::new(Vec::new());
archive.append_dir_all("myfiles", "myfiles")?;

// Gzip tar archive and write to file
let compressed_file = File::create("backup.tar.gz")?;
let mut encoder = GzEncoder::new(compressed_file, Compression::Default);
encoder.write(&archive.into_inner()?)?;
encoder.finish()?;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand why you are using RAM and why `tar` reports an error for large files, let's understand what exactly your code is doing:

---

```
let mut archive = Builder::new(Vec::new());
```

Looking at the [`Builder::new`](https://docs.rs/tar/0.4.13/tar/struct.Builder.html#method.new) documentation, we can already see the main problem: "Create a new archive builder with the underlying object as the destination of all data written". Since you are passing a `Vec` (which implements `Write`), the destination of all the tar-compressed data will be written into the vector. But the vector is stored in RAM.

```
archive.append_dir_all("myfiles", "myfiles")?;
```

This line already compresses the files into the vector, so in this line, the RAM fills up.

Skipping a few lines:

```
encoder.write(&archive.into_inner()?)?;
```

Here you tell the encoder to write the vector you just filled. *But*, it is important to remember, that [`Write::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write) has no guarantee how much data is written! It is a lower level building block for higher level functions which are more reliable. You want to use [`write_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all) instead which will repeatedly call `write()` until all data is written. So since you're just using `write()`, only a part of the data is written. When you have very little data, it can usually be written all at once, but once you have more data, the bug becomes noticeable.

---

So what to do instead? Simple: the `Builder::new()` expects something that implements `Write` and uses that as destination. But your `tar` `encoder` does implement `Write`. Thus, this should work:

```
// Create Gzip file
let compressed_file = File::create("backup.tar.gz")?;
let mut encoder = GzEncoder::new(compressed_file, Compression::Default);

{
    // Create tar archive and compress files 
    let mut archive = Builder::new(&mut encoder);
    archive.append_dir_all("myfiles", "myfiles")?;
}

// Finish Gzip file
encoder.finish()?;
```

Comment: This doesn't compile because `encoder` is moved to `Builder::new(encoder)` but is later used in `encoder.finish()`.

Comment: @NicolasChan Gosh, I'm sorry! I wasn't able to test it, and my brain is not a valid Rust compiler yet :o I edited my answer, the code should work now.